# C++ multi hierarchy in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, subclass, hierarchy

I have a few class in c++ and cocos2dx like this.

```
       Node
    /       \
Sprite    DrawNode
   |          |
ClassA     ClassB
```

And now I want these classes would share some functions. I thought about creating an abstract class to do this. like this

```
     ___________ Node _________
    /                          \
Sprite      __ ClassC __     DrawNode
    \      /            \      / 
     ClassA              ClassB
```

But now I have a problem. if my class C not extend Node, I just  get access or the functions of Node or class C but if my Class C extend Node I get two implementations for the Node functions.
Is there any way around this or simply going to have to forget about the classC and duplicate the methods in A and B, then using a cast to perform them.

Comment: Use virtual inherences ?

Answer (score 0):

You got in "the diamond problem"(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance ).

What are you trying to accomplish here?

- class A and class B are already a node. So you can perform functions of node ( rotation, translate, run action ). We don't need class C inheritances from CCNode.
- if you want class A and classB share the same function. Just declare pure virtual method in class C, make class A and class B inheritances from class C. Then implement it.